# HARK for Speech Recoginition

Tags: linux, windows, speech-recognition, julius-speech

I'm at the research stage in designing a Speech Recoginition app using HARK open source (compel using HARK), but the HARK system documentation confuses me.

I have read the following HARK system documents:

- http://winnie.kuis.kyoto-u.ac.jp/HARK/document/1.2.0/hark-cookbook-en/index.html
- http://www.hark.jp/document/hark-document-en/index.html

I need a Speech Recoginition solution, and the HARK system appears to be an ideal complete app system for my robot audition project, because it includes many features, such as; Sound localization, Function transfer and Speech recoginition.

My problem is that I still dont know how the HARK system is intended to be used or how to use/communicate with the HARK open source.

I'm appealling to somebody with HARK system experience to help me get on the right track.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for editing my question.

Answer (score 0):

Hark works as a standalone server which sends features to the speech recognizer. Speech recognizer must accept features over TCP socket and process them. The relevant parts of documentation are:

[SpeechRecognitionClient](http://www.hark.jp/document/1.1.0/hark-document-en/subsecSpeechRecognitionClient.html)

[JuliusMFT](http://www.hark.jp/document/1.1.0/hark-document-en/subsecJuliusMFT.html)

You can also modify Hark sources and use it simply as a software library invoking functions and processing results.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: Can you suggest me for one more question? I saw HARK has a tool named harktool4, do you know it and can you guy suggest for me what exactly that tool do?

Thank you.